# Get absolute filepath in maven-plugin using Apache Maven File Management API

Tags: java, maven-plugin, file-management

I am currently trying to write a maven plugin which should be able to create/process some resource files during the "generate-resources" phase. Everything works fine but during the process my plugin needs to read some other files as input, so I decided to use the [Apache Maven File Management API](https://maven.apache.org/shared/file-management/) to specify the input file paths. I set up everything like described in the [In a MOJO](https://maven.apache.org/shared/file-management/examples/mojo.html) example.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>my.groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>mygoal</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <fileset>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </fileset>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But I am not able to retrieve the absolute Filepath of the files:

```
public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException {
    FileSetManager fileSetManager = new FileSetManager();
    for (String includedFile : fileSetManager.getIncludedFiles(fileset)) {
        getLog().info(includedFile);
    }
}
```

...as the result is just the filename like:

```
[INFO] --- my-maven-plugin:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:mygoal (default) ---
[INFO] some-file-A.xml
[INFO] some-file-B.xml
```

I am also not able to concatenate the fileset.directory with the filename because FileSetManager does not contain a method to retrieve the fileset.directory value.

So how can I retrieve the absolute file path of the includes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that fileset.getDirectory() does the trick.

```
public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException {
    FileSetManager fileSetManager = new FileSetManager();
    for (String includedFile : fileSetManager.getIncludedFiles(fileset)) {
        getLog().info(fileset.getDirectory() + File.separator + includedFile);
    }
}
```